# FFmpeg scale 720*1080 video to 720*404, it not effect, it play as 279 × 404,and use ffmpeg -i it shows 720*404

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg scale  720*1080 video to 720*404, it not effect, it plays as 279 × 404, and use cmd `ffmpeg -i scaled.mp4` it shows 720*404.
Then I use cmd `ffmpeg -i scaled.mp4 -y -f image2 -ss 1 -vframes 1 ./xx.jpg` to get the thumbnail, but I got the size is 720*404.
Why?
and How can I capture the thumbnail of the video as 279*404?
and How can I scale the video as the size what I defined?

the video link:[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh9cvcmgy8fd97b/tiaowu.mp4?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg's scale filter adjusts the sample aspect ratio so that the original display ratio is maintained. To avoid that, set SAR to 1 afterwards.

```
-vf scale=2*trunc(oh*dar/2):404,setsar=1
```

Both video and thumbnail will be `268x404`.

To resize to `720x404`, instead use

```
-vf scale=720:404,setsar=1
```

Both video and thumbnail will be `720x404` and will look stretched.